# Nothing is printed after reading text from a table (td) using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to print the text for a table cell, but nothing is being printed. It's identifying the element, but doesn't seem to be able to locate the text.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<tr style="font-weight: 600;">
  <td>
      "
    Available Balance
                                       "
  </td>
  <td id="testBalance" class="text-right ng-binding" style="font-weight:   600;">

                                                         664,265.314
  </td>
```

I'm trying to read (and print) the value of "664,256.314" by running:

```
Balance=driver.find_element_by_id("testBalance")
print (Balance.text)
```

It locates the element, but nothing gets printed. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: By convention Python variables should start with a lowercase. As for the problem, I tried it using the `html` you've provided and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I still can't get it to print. I forgot to put the double quotes in my html example (it looks the same as Available Balance in my example -- "     664,265.314     ". Would the double quotes or the spaces between the double quotes and the number make a difference?

Comment: I doubt it. You could try using `get_attribute('textContent')` and see what that gives you.

Comment: That worked for me. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just a timing issue - the balance has not been set/updated at the moment you retrieve it's value. Add an [*Explicit Wait*](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for the text to be present:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class wait_for_any_text(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, text_):
        self.locator = locator
        self.text = text_

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            element_text = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).text
            return element_text.strip()
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
balance = wait.until(wait_for_any_text((By.ID, "testBalance"))) 

print(balance.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

(Thanks to RemcoW)

print(Balance.get_attribute('textContent'))